# how to perform sum() on two variables in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, sum, laravel-5, invalidoperationexception

```
$store_obj = new account;
$x = \Auth::user()->id

$old = account::where('id',$x)->first();
echo $old->wallet;

$new = Input::get("update");
echo $new;

$upd = sum($old,$new);// strucked here
echo $upd;
```

Comment: $old is an array ?

Comment: try this one will work `echo $old->wallet + $new;`

Comment: $old is an Object, where as $new is a variable!
Maybe indeed, you want something like the upper answer. 

`echo $old->wallet + $new;`

Comment: To know what exact type of data is inside `$old` and `$new` you need to use `var_dump` instead using `echo`. Maybe you need to do `$upd = sum($old->wallet, $new);`, too.

Comment: If `sum` wasn't defined, `sum` function doesn't exists. Are you trying to add two numeric values? Use `$upd = $old->wallet + $new;`. Are you trying to add the property to a existent class? Use `$old->new = $new;` (for example). Updating the property? Use `$old->wallet = $new;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find `sum` function in [Laravel helper docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers). AFAIK, `sum` is one of [aggregate method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#aggregates) of query builder. I don't get on what you're trying to achieve, but I'll just assume you're going to update the model with adding those model value with given input value.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\account;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;

class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $update = $request->input('update');

        $id = Auth::user()->id;

        $account = account::where('id', $x);
        $account->increment('wallet', $update); //<---

        $updated = $account->first();

        return $updated;
    }
}
```

I don't recommend the usage of native PHP `echo`, `print_r` or `var_dump` for debugging purpose. Use built-in Laravel `dump` or `dd` instead.

Of course, from code above, you need to validate user input before storing to DB.